# AngularJS - standalone without web server - Error on calling CXF REST service

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, cxf

I call a cxf REST service in AngularJS and it works fine if I deploy the AngularJS client as a web application. But when I tried to access the html files directly outside the web server, it has problem while invoking the CXF Rest services from AngularJS.

But the rest service (GET) works fine if I call directly on the browser. But not in the AngularJS.

I accessed the html file in browser with below URL

```
file:///C:/angularjs/src/main/webapp/views/index.html
```

**Angular JS Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/vendors/angular.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var jayApp = angular.module('jayApp', []);
    jayApp.controller('jayController', function($scope, $http) {

        $http.get("http://localhost:7001/myservice/services/entities").success(function(data) {
            $scope.entities = data;
        });
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-app="jayApp" ng-controller="jayController">

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Entity Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="entity in entities">
                    <td>{{entity.entityName}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Error**

```
Sep 08, 2015 11:47:02 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils logMessageHandlerProblem
        SEVERE: Problem with writing the data, class java.util.ArrayList, ContentType: application/json
        <Sep 8, 2015 11:47:02 AM BST> <Error> <org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils> <BEA-000000> <Problem with writing the data, class java.util.ArrayList,
        ContentType: application/json>
        Sep 08, 2015 11:47:02 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
        WARNING: Interceptor for {http://impl.service.abc.com/}EntityServiceImpl has thrown exception, unwinding now
        org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.handleWriteException(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:371)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.serializeMessage(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:272)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.processResponse(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:118)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:81)
                at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
                at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:83)
                at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:280)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:254)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:136)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:346)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:243)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3432)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3402)
                at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
                at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
                at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2285)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1572)
                at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
                at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
                at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
                at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOOutputStream.writeInternal(NIOSocketMuxer.java:1064)
                at weblogic.socket.NIOSocketMuxer$NIOOutputStream.write(NIOSocketMuxer.java:983)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunkTransfer(ChunkOutput.java:622)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunks(ChunkOutput.java:587)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:472)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput$3.checkForFlush(ChunkOutput.java:727)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.write(ChunkOutput.java:378)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.write(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:153)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:164)
                at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:51)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:2003)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeString(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:436)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.SqlDateSerializer.serialize(SqlDateSerializer.java:51)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.SqlDateSerializer.serialize(SqlDateSerializer.java:18)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:656)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:678)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:253)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1384)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:889)
                at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.writeTo(ProviderBase.java:635)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.writeMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1372)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.serializeMessage(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:250)
                ... 32 more

        <Sep 8, 2015 11:47:02 AM BST> <Warning> <org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain> <BEA-000000> <Interceptor for {http://impl.service.abc.com/}EntityServiceImpl has thrown exception, unwinding now
        org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.handleWriteException(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:371)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.serializeMessage(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:272)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.processResponse(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:118)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSOutInterceptor.java:81)
                at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
                Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
        Caused By: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
                at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
                at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
                at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
                Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
        >
```

**CXF Spring Configuration**

```
<jaxrs:server id="mdmCxfServer" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="entityService" />
        <ref bean="commonService" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:features>
    <cxf:logging />   
    </jaxrs:features>
</jaxrs:server>
```

**Browser logs (F12)**

```
    Error: Access is denied.

   at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:92:209)
   at q (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:89:65)
   at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:86:214)
   at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:118:207)
   at n.prototype.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:133:28)
   at n.prototype.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:130:52)
   at n.prototype.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:133:328)
   at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:19:477)
   at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:39:87)
   at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:19:398)

   Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$compile/tpload?p0=partials%2Flist.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
   at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:144:42)
   at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:118:207)
   at n.prototype.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:133:28)
   at n.prototype.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:130:52)
   at n.prototype.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:133:328)
   at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:19:477)
   at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:39:87)
   at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:19:398)
   at yc (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.min.js:20:172)
   at Zd (https://aja
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have CORS enabled in your server.

To do so you need to include the cors-filter in your configuration.

```
<beans>
    <bean id="cors-filter" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.cors.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter"/>
    <jaxrs:server id="service" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="cors-server" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <ref bean="cors-filter" />
        </jaxrs:providers>
    </jaxrs:server>

    <bean id="cors-server" scope="prototype"
          class="org.apache.cxf.systest.jaxrs.cors.AnnotatedCorsServer" /> 

</beans>
```

And annotate your endpoints with `@CrossOriginResourceSharing` as follows:

```
@CrossOriginResourceSharing(allowOrigins = { "*" })
```

If you want to do those invocations just for testing purposes, then you can also try to run an instance of the browser with web security disabled... To do so start chrome with `--disable-web-security` flag

BTW. The errors in the backend look more like client disconections. They are not related with the problem.

Comment: Very useful. But I have a problem in adding the dependency for org.apache.cxf.systest.jaxrs.cors.AnnotatedCorsServer. Do you know the compatible maven dependency for this ? I tried with <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.cxf.systests</groupId>
 <artifactId>cxf-systests-jaxrs</artifactId>
 <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
 and    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
   <artifactId>cxf-systests</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.3</version>
  </dependency>. All these gives errors.

Comment: Those look ok... Wich kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Can I avoid using cxf-systests artifacts and remove the bean ? <bean id="cors-server" scope="prototype"
          class="org.apache.cxf.systest.jaxrs.cors.AnnotatedCorsServer" /> . I tried like that but this is not adding the needed headers and still get the error . (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).